# Failed to start Watchman watch mode

Tags: react-native, watchman

I am developing a React Native app. My code is error free, but it is facing build problems. I get an error in the Metro Bundler when I execute the command react-native run-android. The error says:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Failed to start watch mode.
```

I also tried adding Watchman to node_modules using the command `$yarn` add watchman.
I get a prompt that it is deprecated.

How should I solve the error?

My package.json contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.3.7",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
}

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have watchman in windows do the following: 
(1)Download watchman zip file from the link [here](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html) 
(2) Unzip the folder 
(3) Place the watchman.exe file in the folder that is registered in the PATH (environment variable) (Eg: Place the watchman.exe file in C:/ProgramFiles/ and make sure the PATH = 'C:/ProgramFiles')

Done! You would never face this error again!

Comment: if you have choco you can also do choco install watchman

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue.Then I have

1. Deleted the node modules and installed them again by using npm install.
2. Then clean gradle by '.\gradlew'
3. Then run the app by 'npx react-native run-android'.

The above steps helped me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install watchman using brew:

```
brew install watchman
```

Comment: I use Android emulator...I did "yarn add watchman". I have watchman folder added to the node_modules, but the ReadMe file says it's a deprecated package and I don't find any index.js in the watchman folder.

Comment: You don't want to have watchman installed as dependency :) Look at my repo: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation-boilerplate. There are install instructions. I recently reinstalled my macbook and had no problems with running my application when I followed all the steps that I mention there. If you can run my repository then there is something wrong with your repository. If you can't run my repository then you should think about reinstalling react native on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

in windows `npm install watchman`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

1. Restarting my system
2. Deleting npm/yarn cache.

Most of the times the above methods worked but not always. So, here's one-time permanent solution (for Windows)

1. Download the [Watchman v2021.01.11](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/releases/tag/v2021.01.11.00)
2. Unzip, Rename the folder "Watchman" and paste the C:/Program Files.
3. Open the folder and copy the location of **bin** folder (would be C:/Program Files/Watchman/bin)
4. Go to Environment variables, search of **PATH** variable and append the copied location of bin

Answer (score 0):

same issue I got on metro Android

I tried the following Steps:-

1.npx react-native start --reset-cache
2.cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd..
3.npx react-native run-android

In mac, I used 
`watchman watch-del-all`
on Terminal 
then I re-run the XCode. It's working

Comment: ... and then what? Did these steps result in the same problem, or did these steps solve the problem? Please take the [tour] and read up on [answer]. If these steps solve the problem, please [edit] the post to reflect that. If these steps results in the same problem, please delete this as the "Post answer" button should only be used to do what it says on the tin: answer the question.

Comment: `I got the same issue when I use npx react-native run-android on the terminal so i did these 3 steps its is working my side`

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all the opened terminals in vs code or in windows and try running again.

Answer (score -1):

Failed to start Watchman watch mode (Windows)

I tried a lot to fixed the issue and at last, I restart my windows now it's working.